# Event-handler setting state from a child component doesn't re-render parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eventhandler, setstate

I'm trying to setState of a parent component(App) from a child component(TableOfContents), in this case a stateless functional component, so that everything can re-render and update my tables. Event-handler(changeUrl) gets called and the state is changed as far as I know but nothing is re-rendering, table is not updating!

```
class App extends React.Component {
   root = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/';
   allTime = 'alltime';
   recent = 'recent';

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { data: null, 
                    url: this.root + this.allTime };
      this.changeUrl = this.changeUrl.bind(this);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       return fetch(this.state.url)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState({ data: responseJson });
         });  
   }  

   changeUrl() {
      this.setState({ url: this.root + this.recent });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div id="container">
            <Head />
            <TableOfContents handleClick={this.changeUrl} />
            <Tables data={this.state.data}/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

const Head = (props) => {
   return (
      <div className="head">
        freeCodeCamp Leaderboard 
      </div>
   );
}

const TableOfContents = (props) => {
   return (
      <div className="tableOfContents">
         <tr className="headers" >
            <td>#</td>
            <td id='special'>Camper Name</td>
            <td onClick={props.handleClick}  style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>Points in last 30 days</td>
            <td>All time points</td>
         </tr>
      </div>
   );
}

const Tables = (props) => {
   if (!props.data) return <p>Loading...</p>;
   return (
      <div className="tables">
         {
            props.data.map( (d, i) => 
               <tr id={'table' + i}>
                  <td>{i + 1}</td>
                  <td><img src={d.img} /></td>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(d.username).replace(/"/g, '')}</td>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(d.recent)}</td>
                  <td>{JSON.stringify(d.alltime)}</td>
               </tr>)
         }
      </div>
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use componentDidUpdate also, together with componentDidMount, for doing fetch logic, if you want to populate table with new data